# Why is this not working in WordPress functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, file, .htaccess, chmod

```
$file = 'my/path/to/htaccess/location/.htaccess';

$htaccess = file($file);

$ht = fopen($htaccess,'a');

fwrite($ht,"deny");

fclose($ht);
```

I'm trying to modify the .htaccess file via functions.php, the CHMOD is set to 777, any ideas?

**Edit:**

Just enabled errors:

```
Warning: file() [function.file]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /home/tfbox/domains/ibrogram.com/public_html/themes/beta/wp-content/themes/beta/functions.php on line 133

Warning: file(http://themes.ibrogra.com/beta/.htaccess) [function.file]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/tfbox/domains/ibrogram.com/public_html/themes/beta/wp-content/themes/beta/functions.php on line 133

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/tfbox/domains/ibrogram.com/public_html/themes/beta/wp-content/themes/beta/functions.php on line 135

Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/tfbox/domains/ibrogram.com/public_html/themes/beta/wp-content/themes/beta/functions.php on line 137

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/tfbox/domains/ibrogram.com/public_html/themes/beta/wp-content/themes/beta/functions.php on line 139
```

Comment: which error do you get? Please describe more details

Comment: @sanders - I don't seem to get an error, it just has no effect.

Comment: `URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration` - what kind of path is in `$file`?

Comment: @Pekka - `$file = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/beta/.htaccess';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
$file = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/beta/.htaccess';
```

makes the requested path a http path.

That doesn't make sense - you want to use a file path.

You could use

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/beta/.htaccess';
```

instead.

Comment: Yeah doesn't work, it doesn't even work if I use a .txt file.

Comment: @Brogrammer  I fixed the mistake. Sorry, it's starting to be  bedtime for me :)